# Why is my menu not showing active class when the appropriate div shows up?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i copied the jquery code menu link highlighting when the content is being scrolled. but it is not working.

website is asking me to add more details and i have none , so writing this. pardon me please. it wont allow me to post this question. have been trying to find the error , but have no idea.

here is my jsfiddle link : 
https://jsfiddle.net/6a8woca1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("div").mouseenter(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     $('a').removeClass("active");
     $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass("active");
   });


//    $(‘.abi’).on(‘moueseover’, function () {

// $(this). toggleClass(‘active’);

}) ;
```

```css
* {

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}


body {

 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-family: 'Adamina';
}

nav {

 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(0, 179, 179);
 z-index: 10;
}


nav ul {

 float: right;
}


#logo {

 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px 40px;
 float: left;
 color: white;
}


#logo h1{

 font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', black;
}


nav ul li {

 display: inline-block;

}


nav ul li a {

 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px 40px;

}


nav ul li a:hover {

 color: #FAFE7E;
 transition: color 0.5s ease;
}


nav ul li a.active {

 color: #FAFE7E;
}


.section1 {

 padding-top: 100px;
 /*height: 100vh;*/
 height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}



.section1 { background-color: rgb(0, 173, 169);}
.section2 { background-color: rgb(255, 250, 236); }
.section3 { background-color: #EBE1C4; }
.section4 { background-color: #CFC9B2; }


.intro {

 /*background-color: yellow;*/
 width: 40%;
 height: 30%;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 display: inline-block;

}


.intro p {

 font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: white;
}


#myPic {

 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 220px;
 height: 220px;
 margin-top: 95px;
 margin-right: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}


.section2 h1 {

 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.thumbnail {

 display: inline-block;
}

.section3 {

 padding-bottom: 50px;
 /*height: 90vh;*/
 height: auto;
}
.section3 h1 {

 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

.art {

 /*Prevent Vertical gaps*/
 line-height: 0;

 -webkit-column-count: 5;
 -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
 -moz-column-count: 5;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;

}

.art img {

 /*Just in case there are inline attributes*/
 width: 100% !important;
 height: auto !important;
 padding-top: 10px;
}


.section4 {

 /*height: 90vh;*/
}

.section4 h1 {

 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;

}



input[type=text], textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
    background-color: #ebe1c4;
}

input[type=Email] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
    background-color: #ebe1c4;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*background-color: #fffaec;*/
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ebe1c4 ;
}

.form-wrapper {

 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

footer {

 text-align: center;
 background-color: #6A8583;
}

.footerlink {

 padding: 20px 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

footer p {

 text-align: center;
 color: #0a4557;
 font-size: 12px;
}


.active {

 color: #FAFE7E;

}






























@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .art {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .art {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .art {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .art {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous""></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Adamina' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:700">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

 <nav>

  <div id="logo">

   <h1>Tarique</h1>

  </div>

  <ul>

   <li><a href="#about" class="active">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#artworks">Artworks</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>

 </nav>


  <div id="about" class="about ">

   <div class="intro">

    <p>
     I am Tarique. A Front-end web developer based in India. I have passion towards web design. I create websites for web and mobile devices. I love sketching and painting digitally. Love restoring torn and old photos to new and colorful.
    </p>

   </div>

   <img id="myPic" src="tariq vector.jpg" alt="my picture">

  </div>



  <div id="portfolio" class="portfolio ">

   <h1>Portfolio</h1>

   <div id="templateGallery">

     <div class="thumbnail"><img src="web template/slide 1.jpg" alt=""></div>
     <div class="thumbnail"><img src="web template/slide 2.jpg" alt=""></div>
     <div class="thumbnail"><img src="web template/slide 3.jpg" alt=""></div>
     <div class="thumbnail"><img src="web template/slide 4.jpg" alt=""></div>
     <div class="thumbnail"><img src="web template/slide 5.jpg" alt=""></div>



    </div>

  </div>



  <div id="artworks" class="artworks ">

   <h1>Artworks</h1>

   <div class="art">

    <img src="https://pre00.deviantart.net/e408/th/pre/i/2016/051/0/4/candle_by_tariqbaig19-d9sfg1y.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/cb79/i/2016/046/0/c/canvas_shoes_by_tariqbaig19-d9rvif6.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/7393/i/2016/051/b/e/glass_and_bottle_by_tariqbaig19-d9sffj1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/9532/i/2016/046/c/b/glass_vase_by_tariqbaig19-d9rvl1w.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/7d68/i/2016/111/a/f/headphone_by_tariqbaig19-d9zoooj.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/8a8a/i/2016/076/1/a/vintage_car_by_tariqbaig19-d9veq0t.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/d51d/i/2016/088/8/b/cadillac_coupe_by_tariqbaig19-d9ww9cl.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://pre00.deviantart.net/38de/th/pre/i/2016/066/0/3/grenade_by_tariqbaig19-d9sqe81.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/c653/i/2017/110/7/f/apple_work__by_tariqbaig19-db6hdmk.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://pre00.deviantart.net/360c/th/pre/i/2017/191/7/7/rose_digital_painting_by_tariqbaig19-dbftno7.jpg" alt="">

   </div>

  </div>

  <div id="contact" class="contact ">

   <h1>Contact</h1>

<div class="form-wrapper">
   <div class="container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">

        <label for="fname">Name</label>

        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full name...">


        <label for="mail">Email</label>

        <input type="Email" placeholder="name@example.com"><br>


        <label for="subject">Subject</label>

        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

      </form>

   </div>
</div>
  </div>

  <footer>

   <a class="footerlink" href="https://tariqbaig19.deviantart.com/gallery/" target="_blank">DeviantArt</a>
   <a class="footerlink" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/mdtariq/" target="_blank">Flickr</a>
   <a class="footerlink" href="https://www.instagram.com/baig_tarique/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
   <p>&copy; 2018</p>

  </footer>






<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code works find but you don't understand what it's doing ... it apply active class when your mouse enter the section

Comment: yes , and it is not applying active class when im checking in my browser.

Comment: and when you check here ? it's working perfectly here

Comment: no. but after that answer which you downvoted. its working there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use jQuery in your code, but you forget to call it. That's the first problem. Then your selector is wrong

try to change

```
$("[href=#" + id + "]").addClass('active');
```

By

```
$("[href*=" + id + "]").addClass('active');
```

And don't forget to add the call to the jQuery library if you use it.

Here a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kg4ubxjp/

Comment: Because '#' is a special characters

Comment: so check his code to see that it's alread working perfectly with this special charater

Comment: why do we add asterisk ? actually i saw the same code in jsfiddle and its working there. this is so confusing

Comment: that is so surprising. what the hell is wrong with my code then . can you please tell what all jquery links do i need to paste ? i pasted the jquery cdn.

Comment: @Tarique why you are including the jquery twice ? clear a bit your code an remove all the useless things

Comment: is your jsfiddle, if you add jQuery lib you can see an error related to "#" in selector because it's an expression 
jquery.js:1541 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#about]

I chose to add the asterisk to simply apply the selector "contains" (about, portfolio etc)